# Making a table with columns even height

Tags: html, css

I have a table with data inside each column, and I want to make them all start on the same level. I am not interested in stretching each table data to be the same height, I just want the tops to all be even. How would I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but have you tried valign = 'top' for each cell ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need just

```
<style>
th, td { vertical-align: top; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely `vertical-align: top` then for your `<td>` elements.

If you're using a framework (ie. 960 grid system) then the reset.css has probably set to `vertical-align: baseline;` by default!